# Meaning of "it isn't the initial cost, it's the humidity"

Tags: meaning-in-context, quotes, humor

I was reading *Babbitt* by Sinclair Lewis and came across a quote I cannot understand:

> But they all felt that it was rather in bad taste for Orville Jones — and he not recognized as one of the wits of the occasion anyway — to say, "In fact, the whole thing about prohibition is this: it isn't the initial cost, it's the humidity."

I think it's meant to be funny but I just don't get "it isn't the initial cost, it's the humidity".

Comment: Could this be a play on http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/It%27s+not+the+heat,+it%27s+the+humidity ?

Comment: [What's this question got to do with the price of eggs?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What%27s_that_got_to_do_with_the...%3F)

Comment: It's an intentional (and intended to be humorous—you're right about that) [malaphor](http://grammar.about.com/od/mo/g/Malaphor.htm). I once had a professor who was fond of these; one of his favorites was *you've buttered your bread, now you have to lie in it* (you've buttered your bread, now you have to eat it + you've made your bed, now you have to lie in it). I believe it was felt to be *in bad taste* because it *was* funny, so Jones was showing the other men up (they were all trying, somewhat inexpertly, to impress women).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a blend of two different adages:

> It isn't the initial cost, it's the upkeep.

and

> It isn't the heat, it's the humidity.

I don't find any meaning beyond that,  so it doesn't really mean anything, as far as I can see.